# History: Who coined the term centre and why is it called

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-history

The center of a group $G$ is the subgroup
$$Z(G) = \{x\in G | xg=gx \mbox{ for all } g\in G\} $$
I know the term center comes from German but I'm wondering who coined the term and why. In what sense if an element of this subgroup "central"

Comment: Have you tried to go to the *History of Science and Mathematics* stackexchange? The same question was asked recently: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/how-did-the-terms-center-and-centralizer-come-up-in-group-theory

Comment: The town center is where everyone commutes.